# Group checkboxes needs required with bootstrap in rails3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for templating. I have a group of checkboxes. I want to use `required` property of `bootstrap` but, when I want to use it for group of checkboxes not for individual.

Is there is any way to impletement this.
Here is the reference image http://grab.by/Hm5m

Comment: Please provide your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="1" required="required" class="required_group" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="2" required="required" class="required_group" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="3" required="required" class="required_group" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="4" required="required" class="required_group" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

You could make it so that the user is required to check at least one checkbox:

```
$('form').on('click', '.required_group', function(){
    $('input.required_group').prop('required', $('input.required_group:checked').length === 0);
});
```

[This solution](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lncw1zm/4/) relies on the HTML5 `required` attribute (and browser support). It doesn't require any particular Bootstrap code, but it uses jQuery (which you're already using with Bootstrap), so you can customize it with the Bootstrap classes and widgets that make sense for your project.

Comment: Not working.. If I click on any `checkbox` and again `uncheck` it, form gets submit instead of displaying `error message`.

Comment: Yup. If you provide your HTML, I can show you how to do this in a way that would be reusable for multiple checkbox "sets".